# baseline vertical-align, but at the top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a vertical alignment similar to baseline, but at the first line of text rather than the last. Neither `top` nor `text-top` gets the alignment right. Any ideas? Thanks!

*edit: This assumes that the font size is the same in the elements being aligned. See comment below by @FelipeAls on the accepted answer*.

*edit: now with code sample and picture*:

What I'm trying to do is vertically align the text in several inline-block elements so that their baselines are all in the same position. I'd rather not do something like nudging things using margins and padding, because I find whenever I do that, I ended up playing whack-a-mole with the different browsers.

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two two two two</span>
    <span>three three three three three three three three three</span>
    <button type="button">action</button>
</div>

<div class="bar">
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two two two two</span>
    <span>three three three three three three three three three</span>
    <button type="button">action</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

button {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.foo, div.bar {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

div span {
    text-align: center;
}

div.foo span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.bar span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

div button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
}
```

[image]

See http://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/3t8v5L1j/3/.

Comment: Please include a code example rather than a link to code. And be more specific: What element do you want to align with what?

Comment: @Jonathan, sorry about that! I've added the relevant HTML and CSS. The jsfiddle has some extra code in it, but what I put here is what's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can only do that with CSS box-model, such as `margin`, `padding`.

This is because the different inline-block elements are aligned at the baseline, but they have different `padding` / `margin` settings, so their text is aligned slightly off vertically. If you change the `padding` and `margin` of the `<button>`s and the `<span>`s to be the same, then it should work.

---

**EDIT1**

Actually, now that I think of it, you might be able to manually set values to `vertical-align` in pixels. Experiment with it (including negative values) to see what you want. It will depend on the `padding`s and `margin`s of the `<span>`s and `<div>`s.

---

**EDIT2**

Actually, `vertical-align: text-top` works pretty well for me:

[image]

Comment: It didn't dawn on me to change them to be different. When I'd set up `text-top`, I'd changed the button's vertical alignment, too. When I changed the first example back to `top`, I must have removed the entire rule instead of just the declaration for `vertical-align`. This works for Chrome 46, IE 10, and Firefox 41 on Windows 8 and Safari on my iOS device. Thanks!

Comment: @Don01001100 There may be a limitation: elements with different font-sizes aren't rendered on the same line, alas http://jsfiddle.net/3t8v5L1j/7/ (I didn't investigate further)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @FelipeAls. In my use case, the font size is the same.

Comment: From my experience as an HTML/CSS guy, maybe it should be a best practice for designers to have the same font size for labels and input (and other texts "near" them). It's hard enough even in this case :-D